# How does Html.EditorFor(...) know the index and item of a loop?

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Suppose you have a model like so:

```
class Foo
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}
}

class SomeModel
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

}
```

In a razor view on the ASP.NET mvc framework, you can do the following:

```
@model SomeModel

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Foos.Count; ++i)
{
   Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foos[i]);
}
```

And the razor engine will happily spit out the correct html containing the index, and will call the editor template with the correct indexed instance.

The `EditorFor` method is a static extension method with the signature

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
```

From the signature, it is clear that it is simply taking an expression, and the only context is coming from the HtmlHelper instance.

I have done very limited `Expression` tree processing, but from what I have seen, I can't see any way that this static method could know the information that it is somehow magically getting.

How can the `EditorFor` method figure out the index for generating html names and get the correct instance to pass to the editor template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing it an expression, not the value of `x.Foos[i]`. MVC then evaluates that expression and figures out that you gave it a collection with an index.
You would get the same result if you removed your entire loop and did:

```
Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foos)
```

MVC will then automatically render the editor template for all elements of the collection and generate proper names.

You can read more about how MVC handles display/editor templates here: [Link](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)

**EDIT :** To see this in action, here's a random piece of code I scribbled:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
var tester = new ExpressionTester<List<string>>(list);
var item = tester.Foo(p => p[0]);
```

You'll also need this class:

```
public class ExpressionTester<TModel>
{
    private TModel _list;
    public ExpressionTester(TModel list)
    {
        _list = list;
    }

    public TValue Foo<TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var func = expression.Compile();
        return func.Invoke(_list);
    }
}
```

Stick a breakpoint in Foo() and look at the parameter `expression` in debug. You'll find under Body -> Arguments the index you passed with the expression. Under Body -> Method you'll see that it is in fact a generic list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the attached article is certainly interesting.  However, it doesn't really answer the question (unless I missed something.)  I understand that I am passing an expression. In fact, I have even parsed expressions to get the name of properties as a "static reflection" technique. But the helper method is somehow getting a *value* from the expression - *two* values in fact - the value of the index, and the value of the full expression.  The linked article doesn't really explain how it gets from the expression to the *value* of the index and the expression.

Comment: For those interested, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607464/how-to-get-the-instance-of-a-reffered-instance-from-a-lambda-expression

Comment: For the slightly more complex version:
``int i = 3; var item = tester.Foo(p => p[i]);``

This is how to parse the expression values:
``var argument = ((MemberExpression)((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Arguments[0]);
string name = argument.Member.Name;
var constant = ((ConstantExpression)argument.Expression);
var anonymousClassInstance = constant.Value;
/* ...and the member itself.*/
var calledClassField = (FieldInfo)argument.Member;
/* With an instance of the anonymous class and the field, we can get its value.*/
int i = (int)calledClassField.GetValue(anonymousClassInstance);``